# Why we should use option in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub

What's the use case of  "option"  in dart and flutter can anyone explain this.

```
  Eg:  Future<Option<User>> getSignedInUser();
```

Comment: Is this `Option` class comes from the `args` package? https://pub.dev/documentation/args/latest/args/Option-class.html

Comment: it's come from dartz package : https://pub.dev/packages/dartz

Answer (score 5):

You can see that `Option` and `Either` provided by the [dartz](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz) package are used a lot with apps following functional programming paradigm. They are called **monads**.

Let's take an example, when making an API call, it can either return an expected value, or an error. Usually we'll return `null` when an error happens or throw an Exception, but this might result in a Runtime Error, and not useful to handle different error types (to display the exact error message for the end-users).

**Monad** allows us to encapsulate both of these 2 outcomes by a generic class.

Coming back to `Option`, it represents a value of one of two possible types. The convention is to consider missing value as an instance of `None` and expected success value in an instance of `Some`. So it present the absent of the return value with a class and not just `null`

Moreover, you can use the `fold()` method to handle both cases like this:

```dart
void main() {
  final car = Car(Colors.black, 'Mercedes');

  final option = getNameAsOptional(car); // Get name of the car, returning an Option 

  // Use the fold() method to handle both case: name is None and name is Some
  option.fold(
    () => print('None!'), // 1st case: Failure
    (name) => print('Aha! Your car's name is $name'), // 2nd case: Success
  );
}
```

P/S: You can read more on **monads** in [this article](https://medium.com/@cb.yannick/a-small-monad-library-for-dart-flutter-project-e49b71205bd0). It's from the author of a different package, but the base concept remains the same.